# Primeng 4.3: Datatable column value 'S', 'N' to 'Yes' 'No'

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I've these cols:

```
this.cols = [
   { field: 'acronym', header: 'Acrònim', sortable: true },
   { field: 'name', header: 'Nom', sortable: true },
   { field: 'commonUserName', header: 'Credencial', sortable: true },
   { field: 'scope', header: 'Àmbit', sortable: true },
   { field: 'transversal', header: 'Transversal', sortable: true },
   { field: 'startDate', header: 'Data Inici', sortable: true },
   { field: 'suspendDate', header: 'Data Suspensió', sortable: true },
];
```

Html `p-dataTable` is:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1.54em" *ngIf="!apps.error">
    <p-dataTable #appsTable [value]="apps.content"...>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="col.sortable">
        </p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

And table looks like:

[image]

As you can see, values are `S|N`, I'd like to show `"Yes"` when value is `"S"` and `"No"` when value is `"N"`.

Data is an array of:

```
export interface ApplicationUser {
    acronym: string;
    code: string;
    commonUserName: string;
    description: string;
    name: string;
    transversal: string;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `apps.content`? Doesn't that determine data that will be displayed in each row? If so, I think you should be able to use `ng-template` with a `Pipe` for example, to convert `S` and `N` to `Yes` and `No`

Comment: Here you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the template columns to defined the columns

```
<p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" field="col.field" header="col.header">
    <ng-template let-col let-data="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
        <span>{{col.field=='transversal'?data[col.field]=='S'?'Yes':'No':data[col.field]}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```